# Can Swaggergen for C# use models from an existing DLL instead of generating them

Tags: swagger

I'm using C# to write a HTTP API and I have a C# client WinForms desktop application that I'd like to call this API.

I'm using Swaggergen to create a proxy (and model classes) then package this up into a NuGet package to consume from the WinForms app.

Swaggergen generates the model classes, but I already have a DLL that contains all of my model classes -- it is used to make the API.

Can Swagger use my existing DLL of model classes instead of generating new ones?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <OpenApiReference 
            Include="swagger.json" 
            Namespace="Company.Product.HttpApiProxy" 
            ClassName="Company.Product.HttpApiProxy" 
            OutputPath="$(ProjectDir)CompanyProductHttpApiProxy.cs"
        >
            <Options>/AdditionalNamespaceUsages:Company.Product,Company.Product.Model /GenerateDtoTypes:false</Options>
            
            <CodeGenerator>NSwagCSharp</CodeGenerator>
        </OpenApiReference>
    </ItemGroup>
```